# Python: How to pass ARGV parameters to another script?

Tags: python, subprocess, argv

I need to create a wrapper script that gets parameters from the shell and that passes all of them as they are, to another script.

In Perl, I would do:

```
system("/path/to/subprocess", @ARGV);
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) with [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) minus the first element, which is the name of your Python script.

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.call(["/path/to/subprocess"] + sys.argv[1:])
```

Example with `date` as the subprocess:

```
$ python3 s.py
Tue Oct 21 09:25:00 CEST 2014
$ python3 s.py -R
Tue, 21 Oct 2014 09:25:01 +0200
```

Comment: Amazing!
By the way, does subprocess.call() works like subprocess.Popen() ?

Comment: Please read the linked documentation about the various functions in `subprocess`.

Comment: @user3322273: use `check_call()` unless you expect non-zero exit status

Comment: It doesn't work with `shell = True`. Is there anything to do?

Comment: What is the command you are calling? What do you mean in detail by "it doesn't work"?